# Proof that the Parallel Postulate is independent from the other four?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I know that the Parallel Postulate (Euclid's Fifth Postulate) cannot be proved from Euclid's other four postulates. Wikipedia says that this was proved by Eugenio Beltrami in 1868.

Could anyone give me a (relatively simple) outline of this proof of independence? Or maybe point me towards resources that could help me understand? Thanks!

Comment: Did you read about models of non-Euclidean geometry?

Comment: The general idea is to construct alternate geometries which satisfy the first four but not the fifth.  You can read about non-Euclidean Geometries [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry)

Comment: @MoisheCohen I have a general idea of how the other models work, but nothing beyond that.

Comment: @lulu Do you then have to prove that these alternate geometries are consistent, since it's possible that down the road you could find a contradiction, hence proving the postulate?

Comment: Usually one settles for something weaker, namely a proof of the fact that the desired Geometry is consistent if and only if Euclidean Geometry is consistent.

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry, then continute to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry#Models_of_the_hyperbolic_plane. Pick your favorite model and then read about it in detail in one of the links. If something is still unclear, then ask a more focused question.

Comment: One more thing: The problem in the end boils down to the question if the axioms of real numbers are consistent.

Comment: @lulu That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea of one proof is that one models 'the plane' as the interior of a circle C *[yes, I mean EXcluding the boundary]*, 'line' as a segment of a chord of C *[here we have to recall that for the Greeks a line was what we now call a line-segment, i.e of finite length]*, and 'point' as a point inside C.  With these assumptions one can easily see that the constructions given by the first four postulates are doable: two points in C can be joined by a chord-segment in C, a chord-segment in C can be extended further [to a point within C!], a circle can be drawn in C centered at any point in C, and right angles between chord-segments in C are always equal.  One can also easily construct violations of the fifth postulate [because extended segments may only 'meet' outside of C].

Strictly speaking, this glosses over some important issues, but you should get the gist of the idea - Euclidean geometry -restricted to the interior of C- violates the parallel postulate.

Comment: Doesn't the third postulate say that given any line segment, we can draw a circle with this line segment as radius? That would violate what you're suggesting. (I'm getting my statements of the postulates from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclidsPostulates.html).)

Comment: @Sambo: That's why you should either read wikipedia or a textbook for more detail. This answer does not explain how to define distances between points and, accordingly, what are circles in this geometry. (They are not the same as Euclidean circles in the ambient Euclidean plane.)